# Can't retrieve email messages from grouped email

Tags: python, imap

I am trying to fetch email messages from a gmail inbox. So, there will be 1000s of messages sent to Inbox and since they are 1000s, the emails are grouped 100 per each email item.

When I tried this method, the program only fetches some but not all and especially it happens with grouped email messages. How can I get all the messages from that grouped email.

```
    import email, time, sys
    from imapclient import IMAPClient

    with IMAPClient(HOST) as server:
        server.login(USERNAME, PASSWORD)
        server.select_folder('INBOX', readonly=True)

        messages = server.search(['ALL', 'UNSEEN'])
        for uid, message_data in server.fetch(messages, 'RFC822').items():
            email_message = email.message_from_bytes(message_data[b'RFC822'])
            print(email_message.get_payload(None, True))
```

The program should fetch all the email messages from the grouped email and output to the file (in my case I am grabbing the href links). How best I can achieve this ? Appreciate thoughts and suggestions.

Comment: I don't see any grouping going on. I do see that you search for only unseen messages and retrieve only those, though.

Comment: Got it, so search won't give the messages out of grouping ?

Comment: What does "give messages out of grouping" even mean?

Comment: so in this case, there are 100 email messages grouped to one email and are sent to gmail from our system. I need to fetch all the 100 email messages from that email entry from GMail Inbox.

Comment: In that case, why are you searching for `ALL UNSEEN`? `FROM a@dre.ss` sounds rather more promising. Why did you try `ALL UNSEEN` in the first place?

Comment: I have been trying ['FROM', 'some@some1.com'] but that just only gives me with some messages. It just doesn't give me all. So, I have tried various combinations and none of them worked. So, seeking the suggestions.